# Facebook Analytics for Apps - under reporting installs/users? (Android)

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

Facebook Analytics for Apps are consistently underestimating the number of Android installs compared to Google Analytics (actual number of installs 40-50% higher). Confident the GA figure is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

Jonas - are all versions of your app instrumented with [the call to 'activateApp'](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android#appActivation) from the Facebook SDK for Android?  If not, then only those versions that are will be reporting installs and could explain the discrepancy you're seeing.